# Convert string hex message to integer on server from client in C

Tags: c, sockets, integer, type-conversion, endianness

Client send me this message `write( sock, "Somethingrfrfrf\x00\x00\x02\x24", string_length );`

How I can parse this message? I need to convert last four symbols \x00\x00\x02\x24 (Big Endian) to integer number on server in C language

\x00\x00\x02\x24 must be `int result = 548;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the integer is always in the last four bytes of the message, and is always ordered in a big-endian fashion, you can convert it back to an int (regardless of your platform's endianess) using something like this (you may need to adjust the signed/unsigned characteristic depending on if what is sent it signed or unsigned):

```
unsigned int i = 0;

i = i + ((unsigned char*)msgstr[msglen-1])
      + ((unsigned char*)msgstr[msglen-2]) <<8
      + ((unsigned char*)msgstr[msglen-3]) <<16
      + ((unsigned char*)msgstr[msglen-4]) <<24;
```